# Know any recent tutorials for the latest version of Node.js with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been trying Node.js+MongoDB tutorials from Googling and old stackoverflow answers, such as http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmawa, http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb, and videos online.  Since these tutorials are out-dated by a couple of years (which is a lot for the fast-evolving Node.js), I've been struggling to figure out how to make them work, in vain and pain.

Do you know any RECENT tutorials that work with the latest version of Node.js and MongoDB?  Thanks!

Comment: THis might be a good place to start.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention any specific module you are using to use mongodb. So to begin with choose one. If you check the joyent/node modules page it shows so many modules you can use to work with mongodb.

Please check the page: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-nosql-mongo. Most of the packages listed have proper documentation. And you can find tutorials on their pages too. The two most used are [mongodb](https://npmjs.org/package/mongodb) and [mongoose](https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose).

#### [mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)

Its documentation [page](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) has

- [Tutorials](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/#tutorials)
- [API Documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/#api-documentation)
- [External Tutorials](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/#external-tutorials)
- [Video Presentations about different topics around the MongoDB and Node.js](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/#video-presentations-about-different-topics-around-the-mongodb-and-node-js)

#### [mongoose](https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose)

Project [page](http://mongoosejs.com/)

- [Quick Start](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html)
- [API Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)

Comment: [The joyent/node modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-nosql-mongo) page says that node-mongodb-native ("mongodb" in your comment) is the "Official Driver", but both are supported by 10gen. Any comments on which one to use?

Comment: Do we must have modules to use MongoDB? If so, what is the module used in [this tutorial](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb)?  Thanks!

Comment: @HaoQiLi The tutorial you mention uses mongodb/node-mongodb-native. The choice depends on your needs. For basic operations use mongodb. See comparisons here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/ix2mTe0bizU and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232562/mongoose-vs-mongodb-nodejs-modules-extensions-which-better-and-why

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at:

- the [GitHub Examples](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/tree/1.3-dev/examples)
- the [Try it in your browser](https://runnable.com/#mongodb/node-mongodb-native/server.js/launch)
- the comprehensive [Readme](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#readme)
- official [tutorials](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/#tutorials)
- last but not least: the [official Documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)

All these resources are up to date.

I know node.js is fast evolving, and sometimes documentation lags, but this case you should not have any problems.

Also: Inside the official docs you find a [few other resources](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/#external-tutorials).