# References in MongoDB / Mongoose / nodejs - parallelization

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reference, mongoose

I want to get references in mongoDB using nodejs/mongoose.

In the documentation I read that there are two options: [Manual References or DBRefs.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/)

Since they state, its recommended to use Manual References, I decided to set up a schema in the following way:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    reference : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
});
```

1. Question: If I retrieve an array of these objects from my collection, how do I resolve the references in a good practice way?

My Idea was to use [Nimble](http://caolan.github.io/nimble/) and parallelize the necessary requests. I wanted to do something like

```
flow.parallel(functions, function() {
    return result;
});
```

where I dynamically fill an array of functions

```
var functions = []
```

which I pass then to nimble.
(kind of this SO-question: [Javascript Array of Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908378/javascript-array-of-functions))

2. Question: Is this practical? The array of functions-thing seems kind of not really the way to go to me. But I don't see any alternative, since nimble needs to be called with a static number of functions.

Comment: hope this link might help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712248/difference-between-mongodb-and-mongoose

Comment: Why not use Mongoose's support for reference [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mongoose's support for reference [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to efficiently follow references.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    reference : { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'OtherModel' }
});
var MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', schema);
MyModel.find().populate('reference').exec(function(err, docs) {...});
```

In the above example, the `reference` field of each `docs` element gets populated with referenced doc.