# Should I use both MongoDB and Mongoose in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and I use MongoDB locally but in some cases I need to use Mongoose. How to use both MongoDB and Mongoose in the same project. Please help me to resolve this issue and please put if you have any references.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB is a database, while Mongoose is the "bridge" between MongoDB and your server. You use it to create schemas and connect to MongoDB. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712248/difference-between-mongodb-and-mongoose#:%7E:text=In%20terms%20of%20Node.,Object%20modeling%20tool%20for%20MongoDB.&text=Using%20Mongoose%2C%20a%20user%20can,management%20of%20data%20in%20MongoDB.) for more in depth answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

yes you should, its a good practice.

```
npm install mongoose
```

Mongoose requires a connection to a MongoDB database. You can use require() and connect to a locally hosted database with mongoose.connect().

```html
//Import the mongoose module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Set up default mongoose connection
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_database';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

//Get the default connection
var db = mongoose.connection;

//Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

If you need to create additional connections you can use mongoose.createConnection(). This takes the same form of database URI (with host, database, port, options etc.) as connect() and returns a Connection object)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-NneoBiLA4 ,you can use this video. it has a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`Mongoose` is a full package, it has all the methods required by a backend. It has a connections function, it has ORM which helps to do CRUD operations. It is like an industry standard.